# Sequence avoiding hyperplane

Tags: functional-analysis

Given a sequence of non-zero  vectors in a separable Banach space, can one always find a hyperplane not containing any memeber of the sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be your Banach space. Suppose you cannot find such a hyperplane, then for every nonzero linear functional $f$ there exists an $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $f(x_n)=0$. Set $A_n=\{f\in X^*|f(x_n)=0\}$, then $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n=X^*$. But, every $A_n$ is closed, and $X^*$ is complete, so, from Baire's theorem, there exists $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that $A_{n_0}$ has nonempty interior. Therefore, there exists $f_0\in X^*$ with $f_0(x_{n_0})=0$ and $\varepsilon>0$ such that, if $\|g-f_0\|<\varepsilon$, then $g(x_{n_0})=0$. So, for all $f\in X^*$ with $\|f\|=1$, you have that $$\left\|f_0-\left(f_0+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}f\right)\right\|=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}<\varepsilon\Rightarrow \left(f_0+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}f\right)(x_{n_0})=0\Rightarrow f(x_{n_0})=0.$$ Since this happens for all $f$ with $\|f\|=1$, you have that $x_{n_0}=0$, contradiction. So, there always exists such a hyperplane.

I think that the separability condition is not needed here.