# sequences and hyperplanes

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Consider a linearly independent sequence $(x_n)$ in a separable Banach space. Can we always find a closed hyperplane $H$ and and a finite **non empty** subset $F$ of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $\{x_j: j\in \mathbb{N}\setminus F\}\subset H$.  In others words, $H$ contains all but possibly finitely many members of the sequence.

If the closed span of the sequence is not the entire Banach space, then the answer is clearly yes.

My question seems to be connected to this one:

[Sequence avoiding hyperplane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529151/sequence-avoiding-hyperplane)

Comment: Your "In other words" isn't right: "$X$ does not contain finitely many members of $Y$" means "$X$ contains infinitely many members of $Y$". This is a weaker statement than "$X$ contains all but finitely many members of $Y$".

Comment: Am I missing something? Doesn't that link answer your question? A hyperplane that does not contain any point of the sequence does not contain finitely many points of the sequences right?

Comment: @RobArthan I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan You are right, the way I phrased it was confusing, hopefully now is more clear.

Comment: If the space is separable, consider a dense sequence. Every closed hyperplane misses infinitely many points of the sequence (if the hyperplane need not be closed, I don't know whether it might be possible). If the space is not separable, the closed space spanned by the sequence is not the entire space, so then it's possible.

Comment: @DanielFischer You are right. I added that the sequence is linearly independent. Sorry for moving the goal post. :)

Comment: @Markus, why don't you throw away $x_1$ and set $H:=\operatorname{cl span}\{x_2,\ldots,x_3\}$

Comment: @Norbert Even if you throw away a vector, that still might be the whole $X$.

Comment: @Markus Again, I do not understand why the link provided above doesn't answer your question?

Comment: @Norbert The hyperplane in the link misses all points. I want it to contain all points, except maybe finitely many.

Comment: Ok I've indicated this in your question

Comment: @Norbert I don't think your edit (non-empty) makes any difference. $F$ could be empty, so $H$ would contain ALL members of the sequence. That is not possible however, just take Banach space with a basis. No hyperplane can contain the basis. So, a posteriori, if such an $F$ exists it must be non-empty.

Comment: But anyway it is correct and more clear question equivalent to the original one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be a Banach space with a normalized basis $(e_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ and consider, for each $n$, the vectors:

$$
x_n:=e_0+\frac{\lambda_n}{1!}e_1+\frac{\lambda_n^2}{2!}e_2+\dots...
$$

Where $\lambda_n\to 0$, and $\lambda_p\neq\lambda_n\neq 0$ for any $n,p$. It is easy to see that $(x_n)$ is linearly independent.

Let $(x_{n_k})$ be any subsequence of $(x_n)$. Then:

$$
   x_{n_k}\to e_0, \text{ so } e_0\in[x_{n_k}] 
$$

$$
  \frac{1!}{\lambda_{n_k}}(x_{n_k}-e_0)\to e_1,  \text{ so } e_1\in[x_{n_k}] 
$$
and so on, we obtain that for any $n$, $e_n\in[x_{n_k}]$. Therefore $[x_{n_k}]=X$. This means that any hyperplane can contain at most finitely many vectors form the sequence $(x_n)$.

Comment: How does this correlate with the OP's question? Your $x_n$ don't seem to have any connection with the $x_n$ that are data in the question. What justification do you have for the claims you make about limits of subsequences of the $x_n$?

Comment: I show that ANY subsequence spans the entire space, by showing the unit vector basis are in the span. Therefore, no closed hyperplane (or any closed proper subspace for that matter) can contain a subsequence. Thus, the sequence I provided answers the OP question in negative.